# Negotiate unofficial offer?

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I've applied for a job and went through three interviews. Today I got an email from the HR person who conducted the first interview. It says that the team is going to make me an offer that will most likely be around $XXX. The amount mentioned in the message is below my expectations.
Should I let the HR person know this? Or is it better to wait until I get an official job offer before starting the negotiations?

Comment: Are you expecting offers from other companies? If so, it may be in your interest to follow DemonLord's advice and delay the start of the negotiation. But otherwise, if that's not the case, I would suggest you follow Joe's advice.

Comment: Just make sure that you are ready to go away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You went through the interviews, now have an HR contact so they are interested, so it is negotiation time. Reply with the statement that you are looking for X, pretty wording of course.

You may win. Alternately they may decline. Different teams have different budgets they work within, and so do you, so ask for what you need. Make sure what you ask for is realistic of course to have a chance.

Answer (score 7):

You should let them know.  The entire reason they are mentioning it before they send the actual offer is to gauge your reaction and see if it meets expectations.

Answer (score -8):

Sounds like they sent an 'unofficial' offer to see how much they can get away with Low-balling you.

Me, Personally, I'd take that as a *massive* red flag - both in terms that they are going to pay like crap and if an HR person is 'leaking' information *before you've even started* then no doubt they will 'leak' information in other scenarios.

Now, assuming that you aren't like me and are still interested in the job - my advice is this:

Although you could start the negotiation process now, it is best to wait till you have the full offer.

Firstly (I'm being charitable here) - they could have other benefits that might make up for the drop in salary (like a Gym membership or company car or *whatever*) and such items would be included in the Offer letter.

Secondly (again, charitable) they've said it's likely to be 'around' a certain figure, they could come up, they could come down - until you know the exact final number, you won't know whether it's close enough that you can negotiate or whether it's so low that it's not worth the time.

Lastly being silent on this point is a good negotiating tactic, they've dangled some bait and are waiting for a nibble, you are ignoring it and waiting for a formal offer letter. This will give the appearance of negotiating from a stronger position.

You can acknowledge the email if you want - something like:

"Thank you for your email, I will review the formal offer letter when it's presented to me" - or similar.

TL;DR - Say nothing, wait for the offer, but consider this tactic a red flag.

Comment: Down voted because of 'see what they can get away with' and 'massive red flag'. Companies have pay brackets for staff levels and will generally offer something in that brackets - lower end, not massive lowball just to see if it works.

Comment: Not my DV. Anyway, I disagree when you say that "*if an HR person is 'leaking' information before you've even started...*": HR ***is*** part of the hiring process, they have their words regarding brackets/payrolls, work with finance dept and it's not unusual at all that they set the maximum amount of the final offer, or cut it. They are here to protect the company and make sure offers don't go over policies. There's no leak of information here.

Comment: Sure HR are part of the hiring process - but if it's not inside the formal hiring process, and is instead a casual 'So here's what we think we might do' - I do consider that to be improper and to be leaking info. Either it's a formal offer, or it's not. Also, assuming that expectations of salary were discussed in the final interview(s), getting an unofficially low-balled, I consider that extremely bad form.

Comment: Sorry, you got this wrong. I have rarely made a  formal offer before the deal is fully negotiated and there is verbal agreement.  The reason is simple: a formal offer is a legally relevant document so there is typically review and approval required. You can negotiate verbally a lot faster. Having the recruiter starting the negotiation is perfectly normal and expected at least in my neck of the woods.

Comment: I had a great chuckle at "HR person is 'leaking' information". What are you talking about? The company wants the proximate salary to be known, just in case the expectations are wildly different. This isn't Mandy from HR department gossiping about salaries for the hell of it.

Comment: @Hilmar - Verbal negotiation is fine - I've done it several times, but I've never had something like the OP's situation. If there is something in writing, it's always the formal offer.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - then they should (IMO) send a formal offer with the Salary. Not to mention that this info should have been covered off in the Interview. It smells like low-balling and unprofessional, to me at least. I mean, it's clear most others don't feel this way - maybe this is more common elsewhere - but in NZ, we are notorious for being rather chill and informal - and I've never experienced anything like this scenario.

Comment: @TheDemonLord: this may differ from country to country (or semantics). In the US the actual "offer letter" is a legally binding contract, i.e. needs typically approval from legal, HR & department head. You don't want to go through this every time you update a detail in the package (compensation, bonus, sign on, benefits, equity, relocation, etc.) so some sort "informal" negotiation is very common. Could be verbal, could be by email, etc.